# Effect of distance on transfer speed (increases over time)

Tags: networking

I'm in Europe and I'm running a web site in the Unites States.

The service provider where the site is hosted offers large up/down bandwith (at good prices).

The server now have very low load (on network/cpu/storage)

As the server is far from me and the route the data have to take is long I have a quite high response time (ping gives 150 to 200 ms) but this is acceptable for me.

Data transfer speed is also good due to large upload bandwidth offered by the provider.

However it seem to me that data transfer starts slow and then reach its peak speed after a few seconds.

**Questions:**

Is this an effect of the long route/distance too?

What causes this "inertial" behaviour of the data transfer speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However it seem to me that data transfer starts slow and then reach
>   its peak speed after a few seconds.

This is expected behavior, especially on connections with higher latency. Look up TCP Slow Start and TCP Window Scaling for more info on this.

> Is this an effect of the long route/distance too?

No, it's an effect of high latency. Latency and geographic distance are indeed correlated, but aside from from the speed of light in fiber, there is no strong correlation between the two. There are *many* factors that play into latency (congestion, number of EDFAs in line, number of route hops, etc.), and distance is only a small part of that.

> What causes this "inertial" behaviour of the data transfer speed?

When a TCP socket opens, the network stack errs on the side of being conservative about how much data it will send before receiving acknowledgement from the other end of the socket that the packets have been received. As the socket ages, and more information is known about the quality of the connection, the network stack can increase the Window Size, which allows more packets to be "in flight" before receiving acknowledgment.

Comment: Thank you. Slow-start effect is an issue (for me) on small file requests (when they cannot be aggregated of course). Is there anything I can do to mitigate the effect?

Comment: The High Energy Physics world has been dealing with this problem for many years and has developed some specialized tools to maximize data transfer speeds over long haul networks.

bbcp 
is perhaps the easiest to deploy, but gridftp also uses the same technologies.

http://www.nics.tennessee.edu/computing-resources/data-transfer/bbcp  The small files problem is hard, you might look into tuning the tcp parameters in your kernel. The utilities above won't help with small files.

Comment: The simplest solution, if possible, is to reuse your TCP connections rather than closing them and opening new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

What you experience here is TCP adjusting it's window size to the conditions of your connection. See [Slow-Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start).